# Read words from file into node struct in c

Tags: c, struct

I'm having trouble with reading word from a file into a node struct.
This is the code:

```
//open file
FILE* fp = fopen("fp", "r");

//create node structure
typedef struct node  
{
      char* word;
      struct node* next;
} node;

node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));

fscanf(fp, "%s", newNode->word);

printf("w: %s\n", newNode->word);
```

the `fp` file looks like this

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
```

The `newNode->word` is `NULL`, why is this?

Comment: By chance. You didn't initialize it, nor allocate memory for it.

Comment: Where do you suppose the string would get stored? You've only allocated enough space for a single pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you have not allocated space for the `word`. When you allocate `node`, only a pointer to the word gets allocated. However, the pointer remains uninitialized until you assign it. Reading into it using `fscanf` is undefined behavior, because there is no memory behind it.

One way to deal with it is as follows: allocate a temporary buffer of fixed size large enough to hold the largest word, read the word into it, then allocate the space for the string, copy the content, and set the pointer into the node:

```
char buf[100];
...
fscanf(fp, "%99s", buf); // 99, not 100, because '\0' must fit in the buf as well
int len = strlen(buf);
newNode->word = malloc(len+1); // +1 for null terminator
strcpy(newNode->word, buf);
```

Answer (score 1):

`newNode->word` is just a pointer. You need to allocate memory to newNode->word before actully storing the data in it!

```
node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
newNode->word = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
fscanf(fp, "%s", newNode->word);
```

This shud do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The newNode->word is NUL because you didn't allocate memory for it. You need either

```
typedef struct node  
{
      char word[100];  // maximum word length 99
      struct node* next;
} node;
```

or

```
node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
newNode->word = malloc(100);    // allocate space for word
```

Answer (score -1):

You either need to allocate some space for the string you would like to store and pass a pointer to that space to scanf, or you could use "%ms" to have scanf allocate the space on its own. For the latter you need to pass a pointer to a pointer. In your case that would be &node->word.